# php with special characters like ñ

Tags: php, utf-8, header, special-characters, json

At first I thought the problem was when I return echo json_encode($row) from an ajax call that results with ñ are changed to NULL. But after testing I found out that the problem exists way before that.

In a sample php file with:

```
$test = "Nuñez"
echo $test
```

the result is just Nu�ez

I've searched around but none of the suggested solutions work. Like:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, or `header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');`. And some more solutions that I've already forgotten, believe me I tried a lot.

That's just the beginning of it, I'm hoping that won't be a problem with mysql since my database is in utf-8 so is my $mysqli charset. But I think I can't say the same for ajax json_encode. But nevermind, one problem at a time. Can anybody please help me. Thanks a lot!

***PROBLEM SOLVED*** I just had to set "Encode in UTF-8" in Notepad++, as it was in "Encode in ANSI" before.

Comment: are you sure that the this string at first place is in UTF-8, before send and after send all headers are in UTF-8?

Comment: How can I do that? I had `header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');` in my code, anything else I should add?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for me

```
$test = "Nuñez";
echo $test;
```

shows *Nuñez*

You may try

```
$test = "Nuñez";
echo utf8_decode($test);
```

or

```
$test = utf8_encode("Nuñez");
echo utf8_decode($test);
```

Comment: Yours function correctly even without modification like the utf8 encode decode you suggested? That's odd...mine doesn't. I'm using Firefox by the way. I could see ñ perfectly from here, just not from my own php files. And the solutions work for one string at a time, do you know any workaround for the entire page?

Comment: i tested the code in FF and IE and it works same in both..you might have to change character encoding of your page..check this [w3.org link on changing character encoding to UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding) if it helps..

Comment: Aha! Thanks..that did it for me! I got this from the link you provided "If you are working with hand-edited files then you should use your editor to save the file in UTF-8"

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Its works for me.

```
$test = "Nuñez";

echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities($test));
```

Comment: yes it does. thanks, but I'm sorry I wasn't clear with my question. I was hoping for an "entire page" solution.

Comment: Did you want to use this feature for support multilanguage in you site?

Comment: Nevermind. It turns out the problem was that I was saving my file through Notepad++ in encoded in ANSI not UTF-8. That's the source of all my problems. Your solution also works so you have my thanks and upvote.

Answer (score 3):

to show correctly latin characters like ñ Ñ á é í ó ú, etc..  in browsers, you have to use iso-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 encoding
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

best regards!

Answer (score 1):

when you connect to your mysql db, set charset to utf-8, like ->

```
$sql_con = mysql_connect($sql_host, $sql_user, $sql_pass);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: yup it is the same as mine, and it worked for my queries, thankfully! `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');`
`$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

Answer (score 0):

consider setting default_charset, this worked for me

ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

Face the same issue with the string "CASTAÑO".

I've tried posted solutions.

I used the `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');` directive.

- The selected record showed "CASTA�O"
- Using *utf8-decode* showed "CASTA?O"
- Using *utf8_encode* shows the proper string "CASTAÑO"